# C# overrididing static variables

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I would like to do the following but it doesn't quite work. What am I missing or where am I going wrong?

I have a base class (ValueClass) and this is inherited by 2 other classes (ClassA and ClassB).

In my code I would like to do the following:

```
var _value = ClassB.Get(1);
```

and get the ValuePair(){Key= 1, Value= 999999999M} returned but when it is queried in the Get function the _Values is null.

How can I achieve this?

```
public class ValuePair
{
    public int Key;
    public decimal Value;
}

public class ValueClass
{
    private static List<ValuePair> _Values { get; set; }

    public static decimal? Get(int? key)
    {
        var _result = _Values.Where(i => i.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
        return _result != null ? _result.Value : (decimal?)null;
    }
}

public class ClassA : ValueClass
{
    private static List<ValuePair> Values=new List<ValuePair>(){    
        new ValuePair(){Key= 1, Value= 50M},    
        new ValuePair(){Key= 2, Value= 100M}
        };
}

public class ClassB : ValueClass
{
    private static List<ValuePair> _Values=new List<ValuePair>(){   
        new ValuePair(){Key= 1, Value= 999999999M},             
        new ValuePair(){Key= 2, Value= 25M}             
    };
}
```

Comment: you can't override a static.

Comment: I know you can't override a static that is why I am looking for the alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't override static methods/properties/fields. You'll have to remove the static for this to work. A better approach may be to use an Abstract class instead.

The `Abstract` keyword forces all concrete implementations of the class to implement the given method/property (a bit like an `Interface`).

```
public abstract class ValueClass
{
    protected abstract List<ValuePair> Values { get; }

    public decimal? Get(int? key)
    {
        var _result = Values.Where(i => i.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
        return _result != null ? _result.Value : (decimal?)null;
    }
}

public class ClassA : ValueClass
{
    protected override List<ValuePair> Values
    {
        get { return new List<ValuePair>(){    
            new ValuePair(){Key= 1, Value= 50M},    
            new ValuePair(){Key= 2, Value= 100M}
        };
     }
   }
}

public class ClassB : ValueClass
{
    protected override List<ValuePair> Values 
    { 
        get { return new List<ValuePair>(){   
             new ValuePair(){Key= 1, Value= 999999999M},             
            new ValuePair(){Key= 2, Value= 25M}             
        };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I can't use the format:
`var _value = ClassB.Get(1);`
to get the value without instantiating the class. That was my original point.

Comment: whats wrong with `var _value = new ClassB().Get(1);`? There is nothing bad about instatiating an object...

Comment: I agree Ian, I just thought there was another way to implement it, or that was more efficient.

Comment: @DeclanMcD: statics are frequently considered an 'anti pattern' in software. They make testing incredibly hard and make your application tightly coupled, so if you don't really need them, don't try to force them into your architecture. That'd be my recommendation at least.

Answer (score 0):

One slight improvement I might suggest to Ian's abstract solution, if you want to maintain the static nature of your child class values:

```
public class ClassA : ValueClass
{
    static List<ValuePair> Values = null;
    protected override List<ValuePair> Values
    {
        get
        {
            if (Values == null)
            {
                Values = new List<ValuePair>(){    
                new ValuePair(){Key= 1, Value= 50M},    
                new ValuePair(){Key= 2, Value= 100M}
                };
            }
            return Values;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because there are two variables called Values